# Коллизия переводов описания меток и профилей

Tags: дефект, локализация

При переходе на страницу участника сообщества, на вкладке `профиль` в качестве заголовка ошибочно выводится "О метке", вместо правильного заголовка.

Вот, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очевидно, что у нас просто совпадают ключи описания метки и участника. Однако, как пофиксить это я не знаю. Насколько помню - мы уже сталкивались с чем-то подобным (*а возможно даже с этим же конкретно кейсом*)

Как это исправить?

**UPD:**

На MSE Алексом еще год назад зарегистрирован [баг](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369294/every-about-to-translate-should-have-its-own-source-string), описывающий данную ситуацию.
Кому не сложно: перейдите по ссылке [Every "about" to translate should have its own source string](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369294/every-about-to-translate-should-have-its-own-source-string) и проголосуйте за вопрос, чтобы обратить на него внимание.

**UPD 2:**

За решение этого вопроса αλεχολυτ'ом была назначена награда.
После чего вопрос перешел в стадию рассмотрения заявки.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/369294/revisions

За что Алексу огромный респект!